# CGI and PHP why? and when?

Tags: php, cgi

one day I chat with a experienced programmer about devloping file hosting system, he tell me it's need to use cgi in your program to work in best way.

so what is cgi ?

whay to use?

and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these links will be more helpful than others. A google search will find plenty more.

- http://htmlhelp.com/faq/cgifaq.html
- http://www.unixtools.com/cgi.html
- http://www.tech-faq.com/cgi-scripting.shtml
- http://www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/web/faq/index.xml.ID=CGI

My impression, for what it's worth, is that CGI is less popular than it once was.

There are only 222 questions on SO tagged 'cgi'.

Comment: thanks, but the essence of my question, is really still need to use CGI nowadays (i mean it can performe thing that cann't done by php).

Comment: I would be very surprised if there's anything that can be done with GGI that a modern technology like PHP couldn't do. However, the FastCGI Wikipedia article link provided by Sbm007 suggests a few advantages in separating the web application from the server.

Comment: @pavium: you mean CGI don't have any preference than PHP in functionality neither in performance.

Comment: I can't comment on the functionality or performance (surely it depends on the implementation) but I thought there might be something in the idea of separating the web application from the server. The Wikipedia FastCGI article says: *This separation allows server and application processes to be restarted independently – an important consideration for busy web sites.* You should ask your experienced programmer precisely what he meant.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe he was referring to [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) and mod_php?

Comment: could you provide us with a nutshell info about it !!

Comment: @assaqqaf - the wikipedia article has some good information on it, as well as great reference links - check them out!